# Realizar un join a 3 tablas e insertarlas en una tabla html

Tags: php, html, mysql, tablas

Nesecito crear un `Select` que se conecte a las tablas `customers`, `orders` y `order_items` en este caso el id se saca de la url, las tablas `customers` y `orders` tienen el mismo id pero en `order_items` el `id` esta en la tabla `orders` columna `order_id` y luego generar una tabla de html. Si no me explico indiquenme.
Aca les dejo un boceto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se explicar correctamente pero creo que solo quieres el codigo así que aqui lo tienes, te deje comentarios para que te guies

```
$idOrder = $_GET["id"];
//consulta para traer el producto
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id INNER JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id WHERE orders.customer_id = $idOrder";
$resultado = $conn->query($query);
//guardamos en un array asociativo la información del producto.
$table="<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>Direccion</th>
                            <th>Provincia</th>
                            <th>Ciudad</th>
                            <th>Codigo Postal</th>
                            <th>Dni</th>
                            <th>Id Orden</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Creado</th>
                            <th>Id Producto</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
    //Vamos a recorrer el puntero con los datos                    
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Empezamos a guardar las filas concatenando a $table
        //Aquí, dado que estamos en una concatenación, no ponemos " en las keys de $fila
        $table.="<tr>
                        <td>$fila[flname]</td>
                        <td>$fila[email]</td>
                        <td>$fila[phone]</td>
                        <td>$fila[address]</td>
                        <td>$fila[province]</td>
                        <td>$fila[state]</td>
                        <td>$fila[postal]</td>
                        <td>$fila[dni]</td>
                        <td>$fila[id]</td>
                        <td>$fila[grand_total]</td>
                        <td>$fila[created]</td>
                        <td>$fila[product_id]</td>
                        <td>$fila[quantity]</td>
                </tr>";
    }
    #En la línea anterior cerramos el bucle
    #Aquí la parte restante de la tabla que no se repite
    $table.="</tbody>
            </table>";
            //finalmente mostramos la tabla
            echo $table;
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio